# VSE: Shrink and overlay one video over another

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have two videos, one is 1920x1080 and the other is 640x480.  I would like to scale the 640x480 one even smaller and overlay it in the corner of the larger one.

How can I do this in the VSE?

Comment: I bet you want to overlay a Webcam Footage over a Screen Recording... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just insert your [FHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#FHD_.281920x1080.29) Base Video strip in the VSE, then on a channel above insert the [SD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#VGA_resp._SD_.28640x480.29) Overlay strip and mute it (`Strip` - `Mute Strips` or just press <kbd>H</kbd>).

For preserving the aspect ratio and the original size of your SD Overlay strip you might need to check `Image Offset` in the `Strip Input` properties as well as your SD Overlay strip is not the same aspect ratio as your FDH Base Video (and as your project `Resolution` under `Dimensions` in a `Properties` View should be).

With the SD strip selected Add an `Effect Strip` - `Transform` with an **`Alpha Over`** `Blend` in the `Edit Strip` properties. And finally transform its `Position` and `Scale` (for preserving your aspect ratio you should check `Uniform Scale`) under the `Effect Strip` properties.

Instead of changing the `Position` in `Percent` (as per default) you can change the `Translation Unit` to `Pixels` in the same `Effect Strip` poperties if needed.

[image: Example of a Transform Effect Strip]

There is a great [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0F5X4b7jug&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=13) of that on YouTube from Mikeycal Meyers.